# Pass NewSheet Event from NewWorkbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have a message box open up whenever a new sheet is created in an excel workbook. I also want to have a message box open up whenever a new workbook is created. So far I'm able to accomplish the new workbook message like so:

I have a class module called cl_AppEvents with this in it:

```
Public WithEvents AppEvent As Application
Public WithEvents WB As Workbook
Public WithEvents Sh As Worksheet

Public Sub AppEvent_NewWorkbook(ByVal WB As Workbook)
    MsgBox ("New Workbook")
End Sub

Public Sub WB_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    MsgBox ("New Worksheet")
End Sub
```

Here is my code to initialize the Application events:

```
Dim myAppEvent As New cl_AppEvents
Sub InitializeAppEvent()
    Set myAppEvent.AppEvent = Application
End Sub
```

I've tried doing something like this:

```
Public Sub AppEvent_NewWorkbook(ByVal WB As Workbook)
    MsgBox ("New Workbook")
    WB_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Workbook)
End Sub
```

But that just gives me an object property error. So how would I enable the NewSheet event for the new workbook WB referenced in the NewWorkbook event?

Comment: If you want to capture all "NewSheet" events in all new workbooks then you'll need to create a collection of objects, each representing a new workbook, and each having its own "NewSheet" event.

Comment: I don't understand how to create the object's NewSheet event. I don't even think I understand how to create the objects. Where would I do that?

Comment: See my answer for how to capture all NewSheet events for any new workbook

Comment: @DrewRush - the NewSheet event fires on the workbook object in the ThisWorkbook class module in the Excel VB Editor - if you select **Workbook** in the object drop-down at the top, you can select the _NewSheet_ event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clsAppEvt:

```
Public WithEvents AppEvent As Application
Public WbColl As New Collection

Public Sub AppEvent_NewWorkbook(ByVal WB As Workbook)
    Dim oWB As clsWbEvt
    MsgBox ("New Workbook")
    Set oWB = New clsWbEvt
    oWB.Init WB
    WbColl.Add oWB
End Sub

Public Sub Init(app As Application)
    Set Me.AppEvent = app
End Sub
```

clsWbEvt:

```
Public WithEvents WB As Workbook

Public Sub WB_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    MsgBox ("New Worksheet")
End Sub

Public Sub Init(wbk As Workbook)
    Set Me.WB = wbk
End Sub
```

regular module:

```
Dim oApp As clsAppEvt

Sub Setup()
    Set oApp = New clsAppEvt
    oApp.Init Application
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding an Initialize event handler to your class, and set the Workbook object!

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set WB = Application.ActiveWorkbook
End Sub

Public Sub WB_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    MsgBox ("New Worksheet")
End Sub
```

I tried this with your code and it worked fine..

BTW, of course, this will only work for the first workbook, the worksheet events won't fire for the new workbook!

HTH
Philip